# Will finally clause always always execute?

Tags: java

```
try {
    if (myBoolean) {
        while (true) ;
    } else {
        System.exit(1);
    }
} finally {
    code.to.cleanup();
}
```

I am not entirely sure, but here's the above code snippet that i feel may cause the finally clause to not execute, regardless of myBoolean's value

Comment: so you couldn't just execute and see ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, `System.exit(1)` prevents the finally clause from running.

Basically a finally block is executed after a `try`/`catch` regardless if the `try` or the `catch` returned normally or exceptionally.

A `System.exit` however prevents the block from returning *at all*.

(As Peter points out however, `while(true) ;` will obviously block indefinitely. A just assumed that the `while (true) ;` was a stub for something that made more sense :)

Comment: Peter, thats what i was thinking too! Danke

Answer (score 2):

Because if **myBoolean** value is true, it will enter into an infinite loop. i think you have misplaced a semicolon after while statement.

In 2nd case, if **myBoolean** is false, the **System.exit(1)** makes the program to exit without running the any further statements.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `finally` won't be executed as the code in if block is an infinite loop and in else block it causes the JVM to shutdown.
But for any other normal scenario finally will always be executed even if you have return keyword in your try block.

```
try {
  System.out.println("Returning from here....");
  return;
} finally {
  System.out.println("Inside finally....");
}
```

Output will be:

```
Returning from here....
Inside finally....
```

Answer (score 0):

System.exit(1) performs a brutal exit of the application, ignoring anything that is on the call stack, including the finally block. 
Bare in mind, that GC will not run as well, so resources that are used by the application might left in a "hung" or "zombie" state (files that are not closed, etc..) 
If this is a question for just the sake of theory , ignore my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, since others have answered the specifics perfectly well already: `finally` is essentially a guarantee that if execution leaves the `try` block *no other* code will run before the `finally` block is run. It does not guarantee that the `finally` block **will** be run. The latter would be impossible; consider a blackout or a hardware failure, in the extreme case.

`finally` is intended to enable you to provide guarantees to the rest of your program about the state of things after execution leaves the try/finally block. `finally` is not intended to provide guarantees to the world outside your program. In cases where "the rest of your program" doesn't continue to run, it's more the responsibility of the OS to clean up after the dead process in terms of resources it has handed out, and the responsibility of other systems interacting with your program to have ways of handling the sudden failure of your process.